# How to locate files that contain a specific word in a specific folder first, then replace it with a different one in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, sed, replace, terminal, grep

i'm looking for a solution within Mac Terminal to first locate a specific word e.g. "testword" in a folder with a lot of text files in it and then replace the word with a different one.

I found the following line to locate a word in a folder with several text files in it:

`grep -r 'testword' "path"`

which works fine but i can't find a line to add to replace the word with another one in one combined command. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Do you want to replace the word wherever it occurs in all of the files? Or the just in the first file it finds? Do you want to replace all occurrences in each file? Or just the first occurrence? Where do we get the replacement word from? Does the process need repeating for multiple words?

Comment: `grep -lr "search" where/ | xargs -n1 sed -i '' 's/search/replace/'`?

Comment: @marksetchell Yes, i want to replace it wherever it occures in all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

For safety, I would suggest to do it in two steps. Using first `grep`, `tr` and `sed` to prepare all word replacements for each files. Check if all is okay, then execute all the `sed` remplacements.

```
$ touch hello123 helloABC helloXYZ hello000                                        
$ echo "hello" > hello*
$ cat hello*
hello
hello
hello
hello

$ grep -lr "hello" . | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/^/sed \-i "s\/hello\/NewWord\/g" /g' | tee replace.sh
sed -i "s/hello/NewWord/g" ./helloXYZ ./helloABC ./hello000 ./hello123

$ sh replace.sh
$ cat hello*
NewWord
NewWord
NewWord
NewWord
```